# how to Keep the maximum value and remove other values of a list with the considration of othere lists

Tags: python

there is 3 lists. the first 2 lists show the id and third list is the Value. how to keep the maximum Values in third column with same id and remove the other Values.
For example:

| list1 | list2 | list3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 17 |
| 2 | 32 | 44 |
| 1 | 5 | 7 |
| 2 | 32 | 5 |

The result should be like:

| list1 | list2 | list3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 4 | 17 |
| 2 | 32 | 44 |
| 1 | 5 | 7 |

this lists have more than 10 thousands Values and It would be great to avoid the loops.

Comment: You want to keep the rows where the maximum values in the row is on the third column ? And everything without any loops ?

Comment: @LukasLaudrain ideally Yes, but if using the Loops is necessary, I will use the Loops

Comment: I will post an answer with loops, I don't think it is possible without loops

Comment: Hmm, such tables are hardly better than images, would be better if you included usable list literals.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'list1' : [1,2,1,2],
    'list2' : [4,32,5,32],
    'list3' : [17,44,7,3],
})
```

You can do it like this:

1.

```
df.sort_values('list3', ascending=False).drop_duplicates(subset=['list1', 'list2'], keep='first').sort_index()
```

or 2.

```
df.groupby(['list1', 'list2'])['list3'].max().reset_index()
```

**Update** for 2.:

```
out =  df.groupby(['list1', 'list2'], as_index=False)['list3'].max()
```

Comment: Under the hood, panda uses loops …

Answer (score -1):

With loops, you can do something like that :

```py
def get_max(t):
    res = []
    
    for row in t:
        if t[2] > t[1] and t[2] > t[0]:
            res.append(row)
    
    return res
```

You loop in each row, if the value of the last column is greater than the other ones, you keep it. You can also make it in one line :

```py
def get_max(t):
    return [row for row in t if t[2] > t[1] and t[2] > t[0]]
```

PS : As you get many data, the complexity of this algorithm is O(n) which is linear.